# Can sleeping too much damage the brain and heart?

Tags: sleep, neurology, cardiology, organ-damage

I heard that sleeping long hours can damage brain functions and harm the heart. Is that true?

Comment: To the downvoter: I was about to downvote this "silly question" too until I googled it.

Comment: here you go. Interesting article: Extended Wakefulness http://www.jneurosci.org/content/34/12/4418.short and this one Insufficient Sleep http://www.cdc.gov/features/dssleep/

Comment: @bantandor that's for sleeping too little. The OP is asking about sleeping too much.

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-) It's an interesting question, but your own research or at least giving a rough number of hours that you consider "too much sleep" would help a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How much sleep is too much?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/3333/how-much-sleep-is-too-much)

Answer (score 3):

Although this question is hard to research - you're dependent on self-reported data on sleeping hours, and there are many confounders that influence this relation (why do people sleep longer? maybe people who sleep longer are more likely to be without a job, and being without a job is also associated with higher risk of heart disease etc.).

However, the consensus seems to be that: Yes, it has been found that longer sleep (which is  usually defined as >8 hours or 9 hours or longer) is associated with a higher risk of heart disease and also of diabetes. I'm not sure about damage to the brain functions, though I'm sure you could find this out easily too.
[This review](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2845795/) gives an overview of studies that have investigated the association between sleep duration and cardiovascular disease.